# 自作パッケージをpipでインストールするとエラーとなってしまいます。

Tags: python, python3, windows

## 状況

PCが複数台あり、メインの開発PCのプロジェクトをマスターとして、Gitリポジトリを作成し、別のPCではgit pullで同期しております。
各PCのプロジェクトフォルダには、venvで仮想環境を作り、共通してENVというフォルダ名にしております。
自作パッケージを各仮想環境にインストールするため、パッケージごとに以下のコマンドを実行します。

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

開発PCでは特に問題なくインストールできます。
しかし、もう一台のPC（以下PC1）では文字コードが原因でエラーとされてしまいます。
各パッケージに関する説明を書いた、マークダウンファイルが日本語で記述されていて、これがエラーの対象となっているようです。

## 質問内容

PC1を開発PCのように文字コードエラーなく、自作パッケージをインストールするためには、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

## 開発環境

開発PCおよびPC1ともに以下の環境です。
Windows 10 Pro
Python 3.9.10

## エラー出力内容

```
(ENV) PS C:\Users\(パッケージフォルダ) > python -m pip install -e .
Obtaining file://C:\Users\(パッケージフォルダ)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\(パッケージフォルダ)\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
          long_description=open("README.md").read(),
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 34: illegal multibyte sequence
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに示された`setup.py`の該当の行の`open`でパラメータに`encoding='utf-8'`を追加してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 各々の環境で該当ファイル (README.md) の文字コードがどうなっているか確認できますか？

Comment: どちらのPCにおいても、サクラエディタによる確認で、文字コードはUTF-8となっていました。

Comment: setup.pyのopenでパラメータにencoding='utf-8'を追加したところ、エラーがなくなりました。釈然としませんが、VScodeの何らかの設定内容が異なるのだろうとは思います。ちなみに、この現象とは全く別で、Pythonデバッグを実行できなくなっており、launch.jsonも開発PCでは大丈夫である記載が、PC1ではエラーとなってしまって、修正する必要がありました。

Comment: Windows上のPythonでのファイル入出力はデフォルトでANSI(各国のシステム依存：日本ではcp932)です。こちらの記事に示されている対策でUTF-8になるので、開発PCではそれを行っているのでしょう。[Windows 上の Python で UTF-8 をデフォルトにする](https://qiita.com/methane/items/9a19ddf615089b071e71), [4.7. UTF-8 mode](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.10/using/windows.html#utf-8-mode), [Python 3.15からデフォルトのエンコーディングがUTF-8になります](https://methane.hatenablog.jp/entry/2022/04/26/Python_3.15%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%8CUTF-8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A)

Comment: 文字化け対策で、コマンドプロンプトに何かした記憶はあるのですが、何をしたのか思い出せないです。コマンドプロンプトを起動すると「現在のコード ページ: 932」とい表示が出るようになりました。しかし、c932の文字コードが化けてしまうので、実施した対策なので、関係あるのか不明です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご指摘のありました箇所を修正することで、解決しました。

**修正前:**

```
long_description=open("README.md").read(),
```

**修正後:**

```
long_description=open("README.md", encoding='UTF-8').read(),
```

#### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version = "1.0.0"

install_requires = [
    # 必要な依存ライブラリがあれば記述
]

setup(
    name='app',
    version=nversion,
    description="***",
    long_description=open("README.md", encoding='UTF-8').read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author='Imagenics.co.,ltd',
    license='***',
    keywords='***',
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```